# How do I make standard library calls from the Linux kernel?

Tags: linux, kernel, c

I am tweaking code residing in the `/net` directory of linux kernel.

I was trying things like printing but I see that there are no relevant headers (like `stdlib.h`, `stdio.h` etc). So how can I do this at the kernel level?

Comment: What about kill_pgrp() in kernel/signals.c?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You cannot use any user space library functions in kernel, You should use only functions exported by the kernel. So, there will not be `stdio.h`, `stdlib.h`, etc. If you want to print something in the kernel, you have the `printk()` function, this is equivalent to `printf()` in user space.

See also my blog posts [Linux Module Programming Part1](http://www.rulingminds.com/llistpart1) and [Part2](http://www.rulingminds.com/syscallspart2).

Answer (score 2):

Kernel modules do not have access to the C standard library. There are a few functions available in the kernel; look in the [`lib` directory](http://lxr.linux.no/#linux+v3.0/lib/) in the kernel source or in your favorite Linux kernel programming book (if you don't have one, [Linux Device Drivers](http://lwn.net/Kernel/LDD3/) is a good one, and it's available online). For printf debugging, there's [`printk`](http://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/printk-formats.txt), which emits messages to the kernel logs.